# App published on Play Store but not able to Connect to Admob

Tags: android, google-play, admob, google-play-services

My App got published on Play Store 24hrs Ago.
**Through the link i am able to install** it in the devices but if i search it using **AppName,Developer Name,PackageId it is not visible** on play store.
I also Tried to link it on admob but the app is not getting displayed, However **previous apps are getting displayed**.
Any idea why is it so.?
package id: tictactoe.example.foodie
Developer name: Akshay Khot
App name: Foodie TicTacToe

Please let me know if anything else is required.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Your app just ranks very low in search results which doesn't necessarily mean it is not showing. It might also take some time for new apps to be indexed and therefore not show in search results.

The app is showing in the search results, it is due to your app ranking low that you don't see it, but if you search for the name in quotes it will show. Search for "Foodie - TicTacToe". I just searched and it shows.

Comment: the app is been Published and has also been installed in few of the devices.

Comment: Installed from Play Store or through link only? I still think it may be due to indexing, and will eventually show. Has it ever showed from search?

Comment: installed from play store.. This is the link -> https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=tictactoe.example.foodie . Yes never shown from search.. I tried searching through develooper name also

Comment: @AK  The app is showing in the search results, it is due to your app ranking low that you don't see it, but if you search for the name in quotes it will show. Search for "Foodie - TicTacToe"

Comment: oh Yes now it is getting displayed in Admobs also without quotes.. might be indexing issue.. Thanks for the help.!